# Plotting 2D arrays grib data using contour and contourf - why does using contourf kill the script?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf, grib

I am attempting to plot contours of 500mb height and filled contours of 500mb vorticity values on a map of the U.S. `h500` and `vort` are both 2D arrays of shape (721,1440).

```
import numpy as np
import pygrib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker 
import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

grib = 'gfs'+date+'.f012'
grbs=pygrib.open(grib)

grb = grbs.select(name='Geopotential Height')[0]
h500 = grb.values
grb1 = grbs.select(name='Absolute vorticity')[0]
vort = grb1.values
lats,lons = grb.latlons()

ax0 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

height=ax0.contour(lons,lats,h500[:,:],levels=30,extend='both', 
                   colors='black',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
vorticity = ax0.contourf(lons,lats,vort,levels=30,extend='both', 
                         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax0.set_extent([230,300,20,70],ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax0.coastlines()
ax0.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax0.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)
ax0.set_title('500mb(dam) Height & Absolute Vorticity(s-1)\n'+date+'valid 12Z')
plt.savefig(date+'12Z 500mbHeight_Vorticity_US.png')
plt.show()
```

The code runs fine when I use `ax0.contour`. When I try to use `ax0.contourf` or `plt.contourf`, the code does not execute, it times out and does not generate an error message or any tracebacks. I have read matplotlib documentation for contourf, and to me there is no clear reason for why the code should not be running correctly.